# window vs. application scope for Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, namespaces, scope

Can someone explain reasons for putting all variables with application scope vs. window scope? Is application scope ALWAYS better?

1. performance?
2. prevent naming collisons?
3. other reasons?

**window scope**

```
var myFunction1=function(){
   //do something
};

var myFunction2=function(){
   //do something else
};

var myObject1={
   //store stuff
};

var myDOMElement1=$('.myDOMElement1');
```

**application scope**

```
var myApplication={
   'myFunction1':function(){
      //do something
   },
   'myFunction2':function(){
      //do something else
   },
    'myObject1':{
      //store stuff
   },
    'myDOMElement1':$('.myDOMElement1')
};
```

Comment: That's not "application" scope. That's just namespaced to an object. There is no "application" scope with vanilla JS.

Comment: There shouldn't be any major performance differences, however not defining stuff on the window will make your code less prone to errors due to non-related or poorly written code.

Comment: @KevinB so you say its mainly about minimizing human error rather than it being more performant?

Comment: Yes, most patterns in javascript are more for preventing human error and making it easier for humans to read/modify than for performance. Look at jQuery for example (even though it isn't a pattern). jQuery is far less performant than native javascript, however it makes it far easier for us humans to read/write/modify it.

Comment: @MattBall thanks for the correction, so given what KevinB said, I guess this is micro-optimization and something to not worry about if we are dealing with a small codebase?

Comment: It's not a micro-optimization, it's a good practice. Keep the global namespace clean. You never know when you are going to add some other script that may interfere with your global variables.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is information hiding and encapsulation. 
Since JavaScript does not have built-in the notion of Modules (or Components or Classes), in order to organize your code, you must employ a pattern similar to the one you show in "Application Scope".

For a more thorough explanation search the Internet for the "JavaScript Module Pattern".

Comment: -@Michael so basically what KevinB said in the comments above about "application" scope being less prone to human error?

Comment: Preventing name collision is also important. It's common to load several third-party libraries and widgets on a complex page, this pattern minimizes the potential name conflicts.

Comment: @timpeterson, Barmar: I agree with both comments. They are both byproducts of structuring the code in modules. The benefits of organising the code in modules are too many to be answered in a StackOverflow post.